# How to read .yml file in matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv

I have a sequence of `.yml` files generated by `opencv` that I was trying to read into MATLAB using `yamlmatlab`, but I am getting the following error:

```
y_data = ReadYaml(yaml_file);
```

> Error using ReadYamlRaw>load_yaml (line 78)
>
> ```
> while scanning a directive
>   in "<string>", line 1, column 1:
>     %YAML:1.0
>          ^
> expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found :(58)
>  in "<string>", line 1, column 6:
>     %YAML:1.0
>          ^
> ```

My YAML Files look like the following:

```
%YAML:1.0
Vocabulary: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 100
   cols: 78
   dt: f
   data: [ 1.00037329e-001, 8.75103176e-002, 1.09445646e-001,
       1.05232671e-001, 6.78173527e-002, 9.65989158e-002,
       1.62132218e-001, 1.56320035e-001, 1.12932988e-001,
       1.27447948e-001, 1.88054979e-001, 1.88775390e-001,.....
```

And

```
%YAML:1.0
---
vocabulary: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 100
   cols: 1
   dt: f
   data: [ 3.54101445e-04, 1.23916077e+02, 9.93522644e+01,
       2.42377838e+02, 3.53855858e+01, 1.69853516e+02, 5.81151466e+01,
       8.07454453e+01, 1.83035984e+01, 2.13557846e+02, 1.52394699e+02,
       1.10933914e+02, ......
```

I have tried it with [`YAMLMatlab`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/yamlmatlab/downloads) but am still getting the same error. Please help how to read these file and convert them into .mat files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parser I wrote and published recently on matlabcentral and github, cvyamlParser. It can handle the header in yaml file properly.

https://zenodo.org/record/2703498#.XNg20NMzafU

https://github.com/tmkhoyan/cvyamlParser

https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/71508-cvyamlparser

It is a MEX-file compiled for linux and osx. You can use the src file and instructions on to compile a windows version.
It will take a yaml file written by open cv and convert it to a structure with the same variable names as provided in the yaml. The variable data type is inferred at runtime, optionally you can use sorting for variables that have a numerical index like A1,A2,A4,A5 etc.
Use it like so:

```
s = readcvYaml('../data/test_data.yaml') 
s = 
struct with fields:

matA0: [1000×3 double] 
matA1: [1000×3 double] 
matA2: [1000×3 double]
```

Or with sorting:

```
s = readcvYaml('../data/test_data.yaml','sorted') 
s = 
struct with fields:

matA: [1×3 struct]
```

Comment: Unfortunately your parser doesn't work for me. The compilation works just fine, but when I try to use it there is an opencv bug:
`Invalid MEX-file '/home/neuroreact/Documents/MATLAB/cvyamlParser/mex/readcvYaml.mexa64':
libopencv_core.so.4.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

But I do have that file. It's located in /usr/local/lib as it's supposed to.

Comment: @Max this is a linking issue, not a parser issue. A few things you could try to check if the libraries are set up properly (I assume you are working on a Linux machine): 1. export the library path explicitly in the terminal you are calling Matlab executable from: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/opencv4. (if parser now runs in this terminal session then your libraries were not linked properly) 2. If not compiled from source install dev version of opencv library trough package manager (on ubuntu libopencv-dev)  .

Comment: @Max 3. Set library from within matlab command window with setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', [getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH'),':/usr/local/lib/opencv4']). With getenv you can check if library is on the path. 4. preload the library explicitly by setting the preload variable LD_PRELOAD. (On linux matlab opens in just another terminal session and all the environment variables need to be in place to allow access to library).
The first thing to do in any case is to check if the opencv_core so is linked properly your system with ldconfig -p | grep opencv_core.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, the first solution worked directly. However, I don't understand, why mex doesn't report such linker errors. I do have to different OpenCV installations (one from source and one from ubuntu repos), but I can easily build and link against either of them when using CMake.

Comment: I see. Looking forward for your update then. I already upvoted, thanks for your support.

Comment: @Because you explicitly link it to the path to a dynamic library, when you build it (if you follow the instructions in the read me), but in order to call dynamically during execution it must be on your path. You can set the path variables in .bashrc to have it auto-loaded for each session, that way you dont have to bother checking. If the solution worked for you please upvote. PS: currently the parser i provide doesnt support multi-channel matrices(1xN works fine), but I will add the support soon

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the linked library (which appears to use `SnakeYAML` under the hood) is not able to parse the [YAML 1.0 YAML directive](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/index.html#id2558757) which contains a colon (`:`) rather than a space in later versions of the specification.

```
%YAML:1.0
```

Became:

```
%YAML 1.2
```

It *appears* that the contents of the YAML file are compatible with newer YAML formats, so you could try remove the directive from the file prior to parsing (delete the first line).

As far as converting once you have the data loaded into MATLAB, you should be able to do something like:

```
% Read the yaml file
yaml = yaml.ReadYaml(yaml_file);

% Load in the matrix and reshape into the desired size
mat = reshape(yaml.data, yaml.cols, yaml.rows).';

% Save to .mat file
save('output.mat', 'mat')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. means from my data %YAML:1.0
---
vocabulary: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 100
   cols: 1
   dt: f
   data: [ 3.54101445e-04, 1.23916077e+02, 9.93522644e+01,
       2.42377838e+02, 3.53855858e+01, 1.69853516e+02, 5.81151466e+01,
       8.07454453e+01, 1.83035984e+01, 2.13557846e+02, 1.52394699e+02,
       1.10933914e+02, ...first i need to remove :(colon)  from each line then i have to parse?? like %YAML1.0
---
vocabulary !!opencv-matrix
   rows 100
   cols 1
   dt f
   data [ 3.54101445e-04, 1.23916077e+02, 9.93522644e+01,
       2.42377838e+0

Comment: @a.kushwaha No, you just have to delete the first line of the file and save it

Comment: thank you sir....now no error with yaml = yaml.ReadYaml(Dictionary1.yml); But still getting error with mat = reshape(yaml.data, yaml.cols, yaml.rows).'; the error is Reference to non-existent field 'data'.....how  to resolve this??

Comment: @a.kushwaha What fields does `yaml` have? `fieldnames(yaml)`

Comment: yaml is a stuct type of size(1*1) and have field vocabulary. then data like ' cols 128 rows 250 data [ 1.61622086e+01, 1.99162388e+01, 1.45940113e+01, 9.71231461e+00, 7.46669197e+00, 7.39586544e+00, 7.86521.......................]

Comment: how to access these data...i want to access all rows and columns and store in a single row

Comment: Ok you should be able to access the yaml.vocabulary.data nested field of the structure

Comment: but getting error 'Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object' when trying to access data by yaml.vocabulary.data

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your guidance. now i can access my data. my data is in the form of cell of size 1*32000; now i'm extracting data by x = cell2mat(yaml); and saved in the form of .mat. this is the right way of access??

Comment: @a.kushwaha Any chance you can paste an entire file here?

Comment: now my problem is resolve....thanks a lot sir for your guidance and help

Comment: @a.kushwaha consider marking this as a solution using the check mark if it solves your problem

Comment: I also tried deleting that first line. But for me `load_yaml` still crashes saying: `Java exception occurred:
Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:opencv-matrix; exception=Class not found:
opencv-matrix
 in "<string>", line 1, column 24:
    projectionMatrixRight: !!opencv-matrix`. Any thoughts on this?